# Failing to generate JavaDoc in a Maven project for the @author value with NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javadoc

In NetBeans I got the following error while trying to generate the JavaDocs for a Maven project.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc 
(default-cli) on project Heur: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
Exit code: 1 - C:\Users\Admin\JavaProjects\Heur\src\main\java\com\heur\App.java:27: 
error: malformed HTML
* @author MyName <myemail @ gmail.com>
```

I don't understand the error, in my knowledge the `@author` tag is correct. It is reported here for completeness:

```
/**
 *
 * @author MyName <myemail @ gmail.com>
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 4-apr-2014
 */
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `<`, `@` and `>` like this:

```
{@literal <}myemail {@literal @} gmail.com{@literal >}
```

Might be clearer to replace the `<` and `>` with `(` and `)` to give you:

```
(myemail {@literal @} gmail.com)
```

**Edit:**

Or as you suggested, just mark the lot as `literal` with

```
{@literal (myemail @ gmail.com)}
```

Comment: At this point, why not to write `{@literal <myemail@gmail.com>}`?

Comment: @mat_boy yeah, that's better, I was to focused on the characters that need escaping, though I'd still drop `<` and `>`

Comment: Do you have an explanation on why usually the codes are commented without the `{@literal .... }` marks?

Comment: @mat_boy the JavaDoc comments are parsed to generate the HTML, the parser is looking for `@` tokens that indicate a special value follows, but in your original example `@ gmail.com` isn't a valid expression and so must be escaped